# Close button to fullscreen mode in Galleria

Tags: button, gallery, fullscreen, galleria

If you have used the fullscreen mode in an instance of Galleria you've seen that the only way to close it is by pressing the escape key.

As I like that functionality since it's really practical, for end users it's not that intuitive so I would like to add a close button in the upper right.

I checked the code to find out where to add that button but I couldn't understand it to make it work.

Has someone already made that? I hope I'm not the only one who had that idea.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You add it using the Galleria API:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
    var gallery = this;
    this.addElement('exit').appendChild('container','exit');
    var btn = this.$('exit').hide().text('close').click(function(e) {
        gallery.exitFullscreen();
    });
    this.bind('fullscreen_enter', function() {
        btn.show();
    });
    this.bind('fullscreen_exit', function() {
        btn.hide();
    });
});
```

This will place the close text in the upper left corner, you should of course style it with som CSS, f.ex:

```
.galleria-exit{position:absolute;top:12px;right:12px;z-index:10;cursor:pointer}
```